# Python Pandas filter dataframe: keep only values if they are a substring of another dataframe's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a large CSV/dataframe with phone number prefixes, that I need to filter to preserve speed. The df is about 300k lines long, and I have a list of about 1000 phone numbers that I want to use to filter the dataframe. I only want to keep the prefixes, if there is a phone number in the list that starts with it.

Example data:

```
# Big dataframe with prefixes (strings):
prefixes_df
prefix, country
31, Netherlands
316, Netherlands special
24, Portugal         # will be dropped because no phone nr in the list starts with 24
2471, Portugal ABC   # will be dropped
82, Italy
...

# Smaller list with relevant phone numbers 
phone_numbers
['316938299', '82027777', '31223459']
```

I need a filter that says: **if prefix is the leading substring of one of these phone numbers, keep it**.

Ideal output, the large dataframe with only relevant prefixes:

```
prefixes_df_filtered
prefix, country
32, Netherlands 
316, Netherlands special
82, Italy
```

I have looked into pandas `startswith` method, but unfortunately I can't quite figure out how to use it to filter the large prefixes dataframe, instead of the phone numbers. Perhaps there's a way to do this with regex that I don't know about...

I hope someone can help me out with a solution.

Comment: What does your expected output look like?

Comment: Are you trying to find out which country a phone number belongs to?

Comment: Apologies, I edited the post with my expected output. Ideally, I want to only keep rows in the df if their 'prefix' value is a (beginning) substring of one of the phone numbers in the list.

Comment: Your approach will have serious performance issues, but I think I have a better work around

Comment: Yes everything I've tried so far runs very slowly since the df is so big. I'd love to see your solution as I'm out of ideas at this point.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post your code

Answer (score 0):

Use a comprehension:

```
mask = df['prefix'].astype(str) \
                   .apply(lambda x: any(x == p[:len(x)] for p in phone_numbers))
out = df[mask]
print(out)

# Output:
   prefix              country
0      31          Netherlands
1     316  Netherlands special
4      82                Italy
```

Comment: This seems to work! The only minor issue is that a short prefix like "1"  (United States) also gets a True flag, because technically speaking a phone number "116" (Canada) also starts with "1".  Can I eventually get the correct country label by filtering the longest prefix?

Comment: Question: 300k prefix is long. Do you have duplicate?

Comment: No duplicates unfortunately... Some prefixes are very long (7+ digits) because they are labeled with very specific country/provider names.